# Haskell one way `dupTChan`

Tags: haskell, stm

Is there any function like [`dupTChan`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-2.4.3/docs/Control-Concurrent-STM-TChan.html#v:dupTChan) except that when you do:

```
newChan = dupTChanOneWay oldChan
```

Anything written to `oldChan` is written to `newChan`, but not the other way around?

Comment: You could have a couple of channels and a thread that does the routing.  Is that not acceptable for some reason?

Comment: Actually, I just started to do that. I was just wondering if there was a more elegant way.

Comment: It's a fun question.  After some thought I don't believe this can be accomplished with `TChan`s as they are currently structured.  You can, however, define your own `TChan` like type and operations in its own module with this additional feature - it shouldn't be too hard if that interests you.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson -- since I think this is the best set of answers this question will get, maybe you can add them as a real answer to close this out from unanswered questions?

Answer (score 0):

I actually think this is possible-ish without a routing thread. Its not quite the data structure requested -- an actual TChan -- but it does yield a structure you can read from from "two sources" but where you can write *exclusively* to.

The notion is simple. Just dup your initial TChan. Now, also create a new, fresh TChan. Now, you can read from the dup'd chan `orElse` the new chan -- this gives you an "Output" channel that effectively merges your two input channels. Now, writing to the initial channel writes to both, and writing to the new channel writes to your new merged "channel" exclusively.